# Why is C++ more restrictive regarding forward declaration of function prototypes (signatures)?

Tags: c++, c, function, gcc, compiler-errors

I noticed that C++ is more restrictive than C with regards to declaring function signatures before using them even if function definitions are declared after the function that actually calls them?

I always thought that C is more restrictive but it seems like this is not the case.

Why has the philosophy changed when making the standards for C++ programming language?

For example the following code runs compiles fine on `gcc` command but outputs an error when trying to compile with `g++`

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a=sum(4,6);
    printf("%d",a);
    return 0;
}

int sum(int a,int b)
{
    return a+b;
}
```

The error is

```
‘sum’ was not declared in this scope
```

Comment: The first thing you need to remember is that C and C++ are *two totally different languages*. Once you remember that it should be easy to not compare the two, even though they have similar syntax for many things.

Comment: "compiles fine" is "compiles with warnings" - which for me does not qualify as "fine"

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I know they are two totally different languages. However my question is WHY was this change introduced in C++ and NOT in the latter standards in C?      Although C++ and C are different languages C++ was inspired by C so it could be viewed as a continuation somehow. At least this is how I see it. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Because Bjarne Stroustrup saw this as weakness of K&R C and C90. Heck, even the ISO C committee saw this as a weakness and made things stricter in C99.

Comment: @StoryTeller What was the change in the C99 standard that made this stricter?

Comment: Read the __Old-style (K&R) function declaration__ here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/function_declaration and __C89__ was the change specification not C99

Comment: Yes, the philosophy has changed. The "philosopher" behind it was quite a bit different, too.

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434763/are-prototypes-required-for-all-functions-in-c89-c90-or-c99

Comment: @RichardCritten Does the K&R C style refers to the PRE-ANSI C?

Comment: [Have a read](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#Forewordp7). This is a summary of the changes between C90 and C99, from the standard itself.

Comment: This is not conforming in modern C. Please put up warning levels of your compiler, and it will tell you.

Comment: Related: [Questions about C Function Prototypes and Compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16084859/335858)

Comment: @JensGustedt If a program compiles with warnings does this mean that it is non-conforming?

Comment: While nitpicking (and unrelated to your question) but GCC is the abbreviation for GNU Compiler Collection. If you mean the GCC C compiler then use `gcc`, and for the C++ compiler use `g++` (both in lower-case letters).

Comment: Yes, it can still mean that it is non-conforming. C compilers only have to complain about constraint violations. Also any more modern gcc should complain about this code, probably yours is still fixed to C89. C has had two revisions C99 and C11 since then.

Comment: "Why is one language is designed differently from another" type questions tend to be open-ended questions with no definite, canonical answer. Voted to close as too broad.

Answer (score 23):

In older (before C99) C standard, there's a thing called "implicit function declaration" which has been removed since C99.
So if you compile in C90 mode, a compiler has to support that "feature". Whereas in C++, "implicit function declaration" has never been there. So GCC errors out. Your code is not valid in modern C (C99 or later) either.

Compile with stricter compiler switches (e.g. `-std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors`) and pay attention to all diagnostics.

Comment: @cmaster The way you compile is wrong, don't ask me how you managed. `gcc -std=c11 -pedantic-errors` gives `error: implicit declaration of function 'sum' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]`

Comment: @cmaster No. The C standard only requires that the compiler must give a "diagnostic message" for standard violations. The terms "error" and "warning" don't exist in the C standard.

Comment: Ah, I stand corrected. Sorry.

Comment: For new code and current GCC, I recommend `-std=gnu11 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wstrict-prototypes -Wwrite-strings`. Use of the `-std=c` mode instead of the `-std=gnu` mode does _not_ catch additional portability problems; it only disables library features that you may want to use (with proper ifdeffage) and enables misfeatures like trigraphs. There are many more `-W` switches that _could_ be useful, but you have to consider whether each is appropriate for your code. Do _not_ use `-Werror` nor `-pedantic-errors` without a documented way to turn them off without modifying the Makefiles.

Comment: implicit function declaration only really worked on posix platforms anyway.

Comment: @Joshua It was valid back then and a part of C90. So if it didn't work on non-POSIX systems, I'd consider them as non-compliant (with respect to C90/K&R).

Comment: @usr: It never worked elsewhere because sizeof(int) was not guaranteed to be the same as sizeof(void*).

Comment: @Joshua that doesn't mean it didn't work though. It'd work for functions that returned int. Just not ones that returned a pointer. But the standard never guaranteed the latter.

Comment: @Muzer: The most common implicitly declared function I found in old code was malloc!

Comment: @Joshua That's because `stdlib.h` didn't exist before C89 - and that is one of the more important reasons why we yell at people to not cast the result of `malloc`, because the implicit declaration is wrong if `sizeof(void*)>sizeof(int)`, which the compiler will only reliably diagnose if you don't have a cast in there.

Answer (score 16):

> I always thought that C is more restrictive but it seems like this is not the case.

You have it backward.  In nearly all the places where C++ *isn't* a superset of C, it is because C++ is more restrictive.  The C++ type system is stricter than the C type system, legacy features like the one you tripped over ("implicit declaration") are removed, there are many more reserved words, etc.

It is true that C++ has many more *features* than C, but you mustn't confuse the number of features a language has with a lack of restrictions.  A major aspect of the design philosophy of the ML/Haskell language family is to provide lots and lots of features but also lots and lots of strictness.

Comment: thanks for the information. So C is more old and primitive and maybe because of that is also less restrictive. But C++ provides the same level of low level access as C does right? Isn't the amount of access to low level functions related to less restrictiveness? I am getting confused myself :(

Comment: @JenniferAnderson - Noooo. Zwol never insinuated that. C is different!

Comment: No, none of the two is more restrictive than the other. They are just different and have different rules.

Comment: @JenniferAnderson C is certainly simpler (I would take primitive as an insult), but it is certainly not "older". Both languages are actively developped.

Comment: This should be a comment since it doesn't answer the question "Why is C++ more restrictive regarding forward declaration of function prototypes (signatures)?".

Comment: @JensGustedt Oh but C is terribly old! Just like C++! It's like comparing dinosaurs of the Jurassic period with dinosaurs of the Cretaceous period :) I wouldn't call either modern. Though unfortunately these languages have not died out like most other dinosaurs, because mankind has not yet invented a replacement for them.

Comment: @Lundin, I just said that it is not older :) and I wouldn't say that it is unfortunate.

Comment: @JenniferAnderson I would consider low-level access to be a feature (available, in different ways, in both C and C++), rather than a lack of strictness.  Strictness is about the overall design of the language rather than any specific thing you can or cannot do.  It's possible to have low-level access in both strict languages (Ada, Rust) and unstrict languages (assembly).  N.B. I wouldn't describe C or C++ as either strict or unstrict.

Comment: @Lundin C? old? Look at Fortran — and it's still being updated and used to write new code!

Answer (score 12):

C originally allowed functions to be called from the program without having been defined, allowing for them to be "defined later". And then if you didn't define the function, the compiler simply made up a calling convention such as "ok I don't know what this function returns, so lets guess that it returns int". Similar assumptions could be made for the parameters... which you could optionally define the types for. Old "K&R style" C functions looked like

```
int func (a, b)
  int a;
  int b;
{
   ...
}
```

To force the type of the parameters, you would have to use so-called "prototype format", with a forward declaration like:

```
int func (int a, int b); // function prototype since the parameter types are explicit
```

All of the implicit function declaration behavior was plain dangerous nonsense and lead to fatal bugs. Yet this dangerous behavior was only partially phased out in the 1990 years standardization. The compiler was still allowed to make implicit assumptions about the function if no prototype was visible. (For example, this is why malloc used to freak out completely if you forgot to include stdlib.h.)

This is why your code compiles, you are using an old version of gcc (4.x or older) which defaults to `-std=gnu90`, which uses the 1990 years C standard + non-standard extensions. Newer versions of gcc, 5.0 or later, default to `-std=gnu11` which is the current C standard (C11) + non-standard extensions.

C++ never allowed this behavior, and C fixed it too, with the C99 standard in the year 1999. Even if you have an old gcc compiler, you should be able to compile with `gcc -std=c99 -pedantic-errors`, which means "actually follow the C standard, 1999 years version". Then you get compiler errors if no proper function declaration/definition is visible before calling a function.

Answer (score 1):

There are many reasons. One of them is function overloading:

```
void func(double);
// void func(int);

int main()
{
    func(1);
}
```

If I uncomment the line with `void func(int x);`, it will be called, otherwise `1` will be promoted to `double` and `void func(double)` will be called.

Comment: Not in C.  C does not have overloading, so if you uncomment the second declaration of `func()` then a conforming C compiler will at minimum issue a diagnostic.  If the compiler creates an executable anyway then C does not define its behavior.

Comment: Exactly! Adding new features often requires adding restrictions. In C you can name a type `class`, but in C++ you can't because it is a reserved keyword.

Answer (score 1):

When a C compiler sees a call to a function that it doesn't know about, it guesses what the return value and the parameter types should be. The return type is guessed as int, and the parameter types are guessed to be the same as the value passed in after applying the "usual promotions".

So if you just call

```
double result = cube (1);
```

the compiler guesses that the function "cube" has one argument of type int, and returns int.

What happens if that "guess" is wrong? Tough. You have undefined behaviour, your code may crash or worse.

Because of this "guessing", the call sum (4, 6) is allowed in C, and because the actual function had all the right types (two arguments of type int, return value has type in) it actually works. But this is obviously a very dangerous thing to do.

Because it is so dangerous, C++ doesn't implicit declarations (that is the C++ compiler isn't allowed to guess the argument types. That's why it doesn't compile.

There are a few languages around nowadays where the compiler doesn't need a function to be declared *before* it is used.